# How to get a set of elements in a list based on element index in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have one list and another list contains the index I am interested in. e.g

```
val a=List("a","b","c","d")
val b=List(2,3)
```

Then I need to return a list whose value is List("b","c"), since List(2,3) said I like to take the 2nd and 3rd element from element "a". How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val results = b.map(i => a(i - 1))
```

Comment: How to make it in java?

Comment: @OliviaWang - In java 8 something like `List<String> results = b.stream().select(i -> a.get(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());` should work. In java 7 and below you'll need to use a `for`: `List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>(); for(Integer i : b) { results.add(a.get(i)); }`

Comment: Thanks very much, I want to do that in O(n).

Answer (score 2):

I like the order of my expressions in the code to reflect the order of evaluation, so I like using the scalaz pipe operator to do this kind of thing `|>`

```
b.map(_ - 1 |> a)
```

It's especially natural when one is used to writing bash scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this `apply` method which checks (avoids) possible `IndexOutOfBoundsException`,

```
implicit class FetchList[A](val in: List[A]) extends AnyVal { 
  def apply (idx: List[Int]) = for (i <- idx if i < in.size) yield in(i-1) 
}
```

Thus

```
a(b)
res: List[String] = List(b, c)
```